# Variable names seperated with '-' is not recognised by angular application

Tags: html, angularjs

When I define a model name in two words separated by '-' example: "first-name", it returns me zero instead of the actual value. Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/visabuyuxu/edit?html,js,output
Can someone help me understand this, I am a new bee to angular.

Comment: `-` character is not valid in javascript variable names because it's actually the subtraction operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable names containing `-` are not supported in JavaScript as a whole. The parser will interpret it as a subtraction operator.

You need to use either underscores `_` or `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the hyphen (`-`) character inside of javascript variables because it is an operator, the subtraction operator to be precise. Try removing them or replacing the hyphens with the `_` character. There's also [camelCasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

```
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name">
<div ng-bind="name"></div>
<div ng-init="firstName='John'"></div>
<p ng-bind="firstName"></p>
```

Comment: It works with camelCasing or replacing it by an '_', But I was clueless on how it wasn't working when separated by '-', thank you all for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Readability

use Ankh "You need to use either underscores _ or camelCase."